# What is the meaning of [:, 1:] after np.genfromtxt()?

Tags: python, numpy, square-bracket

I am struggeling with python now. i'm trying this [script](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/blob/master/examples/people.py).
I am sure this is a very common syntax in python, but it is so generic I can't find any explanation that make sense to me.

Can you help me to understand the meaning of **[:, 0]** and **[:, 1:]** in the following lines of code?

```
syms = np.genfromtxt('people.csv', dtype=str, delimiter=',')[:, 0] 

X = np.genfromtxt('people.csv', dtype=object, delimiter=',')[:, 1:]
```

people.csv

```
|       |   |   | |  
|-------|---|---|-|  
|Marc   | .2| -2|A|  
|Martine|-.2|  0|A|  
|Max    | .2| .2|A|  
|Maxine | .2| .1|A|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's using slice notation to extract specific rows and columns from the dataset.

`[:, 0]` means *all rows*, *column 0*.

`[:, 1:]` means *all rows*, *columns 1 through n* (all columns except 0).

See [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1288) for a good explanation of Python slicing notation.

Comment: I didn't know this is the "slice notation". Searching "Slicing notation python" returns lots of docs, I just missed what to search for.